# Why is sales tax collected again when selling a used vehicle (or any selling any item multiple times)?

Tags: sales-tax

Why is sales tax charged on a used vehicle purchased from an individual?  When a vehicle is purchased new the sales tax is paid on it at that point.  If I, as an individual, sell the vehicle later, I do not get a tax credit to use against another vehicle like I do if I trade it in...seems like the states are collecting tax on an object numerous times...this does not happen with other consumer goods like tv's, furniture and the like...so why can they do it on cars?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because. the only possible answer to "why" on taxes is "because we live in a socuety, and that's society's consensus as expressed in its laws."

Comment: His question is not "why do I have to pay tax?", it is "why does this tax apply to this situation?"  I think the question is valid.

Comment: But the answer is still "because it seemed kike a good compromise when the law was being considered" -- and you can't get past that without knowing everything ekse tgat was being hoe=rse-readed at the time, the personalities involved, the social context at the time... And if anything, it's a law or economics question, not a personal finance question. Sorry, Offtipic _and_ Opinion.

Comment: Because the government wants the money :-)  (I'm real tempted to add a 'Duh!' here.)  And since vehicles, unlike most things, usually have to be registered when sold, it can collect such a tax without spending more on enforcement than it would collect.

Comment: You've basically identified the difference between **sales tax** and **value added tax**. Sales tax taxes a sale. Value Added Tax (VAT) taxes additional value added to the object since the last VAT was charged. Sales tax is very common in the US, while VAT is very common in Europe. As to why - the answer is: because.

Comment: @keshlam you're right, I agree.

Comment: In addition, some states have [exceptions](https://trustfile.avalara.com/blog/should-you-charge-sales-tax-on-your-craigslist-sales/) to the sales tax laws for someone running the occasional garage sale, since it would otherwise be a significant paperwork burden for not a lot of money (whether the buyers still technically owe use tax would depend on state law). Selling a car already comes with a bunch of government paperwork, so the tax can be collected more efficiently then for an old sofa.

Answer (score 4):

It's called a **sales** tax, not an **object** tax.  The state is taxing your *sale* of an item.  Regardless of how many times a particular object is sold, it is each *sale* itself that is taxed.

You are supposed to collect sales tax each and every time you make a sale of most objects.  If you purchase something and do not pay sales tax, your are supposed to report it to your state and pay use tax.  Of course, most people don't actually do this, *but that does not make tax go away.*  Cars are generally more "formalized" transactions involving state registrations, so it is an opportunity for your state to enforce the tax on you, *a tax you genuinely owe.*

Comment: True, but it sucks, eh?